# Add class active when clicking menu link with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<div id="top" class="shadow">
  <ul class="gprc"> 
   <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/">Home</a></li> 
   <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link1/">Text1</a></li> 
   <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link2/">Text2</a></li> 
   <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link3/">Text3</a></li> 
   <li><a href="http://www.domain.com/link4">Text4</a></li> 
 </ul>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = setActive;
function setActive() {
    aObj = document.getElementById('top').getElementsByTagName('a');
    var found = false;
    for (i = 0; i < aObj.length; i++) {
        if (document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href) >= 0) {
            aObj[i].className = 'active';
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        aObj[0].className = 'active';
    }
}
```

The problem is that the menu home link remains selected or active all the time even if i click on other links and I would like to make it not selected on loading of the page and also to remain non-selected while other link that i clicked and i am on the specific landing page remains selected. Please only Javascript no JQUERY.

Comment: Indeed, indexOf searched a string for another string, and the first hrefs is present in all the other href, so when visiting any of those adresses the first href will always match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.onload = setActive;
function setActive() {
    var aObj = document.getElementById('top').getElementsByTagName('a');
    var found = false;
    for(var i=aObj.length-1; i>=1 && !found; i--) {
        if(document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href)>=0) {
            aObj[i].className='active';
            found = true;
        }
    }
    //if you never want home selected remove the next
    if(!found && document.location.href.replace(/\/$/, "") == aObj[0].href.replace(/\/$/, ""))
         aObj[0].className = 'active';
}
```

With this way you start at the end of the list, and when you find a coincidence it stop the search of an active link.

I hope it helps you

Comment: Works well, but one thing that i requested, the home link i would like it non active in anyway, like when the page loads.

Comment: That doesnt fix his code - from what I see all you've done is a slight  optimization and removed the global variable `i`. Note `aObj` is still global.

Comment: @Adrian ok I changed it and the code never evaluates the home link. Only will have active class name the other links. Now I evaluate if the link was not found after the for, and if it is exactly the home link.

Comment: @ccsakuweb Exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @Adrian I have made a little modification. If you want to select home link, the problem with == is that maybe the link has slash at the end and the url does not. So you can remove the last slash if exist doing: .replace(/\/$/, ""). I'm happy I could help you ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
function setActive() {
    var top = document.getElementById('top'),
        aObj = top.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        href = document.location.href,
        found = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < aObj.length || !found; i++) {
        if (href.indexOf(aObj[i].href) >= 0) {
            aObj[i].className = 'active';
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        aObj[0].className = 'active';
    }

    //Listen for link clicks
    function listener(e) {
        if(e.target.tagName === "A") {
            for (var i = 0; i<aObj.length; i++) {//remove previous class
                aObj[i].className = "";
            }
            e.target.className = "active";
        }
    }
    if(top.addEventListener) {
        top.addEventListener(listener);
    } else if(top.attachEvent) {
        top.attachEvent(listener);
    }
}
```

You're going to need to listen to the click event so you can determine if one of your links is pressed. I'm going to do this using some simple delegation